# Read/write to Downloads folder denied after targeting Android SDK version 29

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions

My Flutter app needs to read from and write to the Download folder (`/storage/emulated/0/Download`, more precisely).

Prior to targeting the SDK version 29 (`targetSdkVersion 29` in build.gradle), this went well, only by requesting

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

To my surprise, after deploying a new version to my phone, the app started to raise access denied errors when trying to access that folder, despite having granted access for the two permissions mentioned above. I suppose this was because I changed the targetSDKVersion to 29.

The solution was to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to the `<app>` node in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

However, it seems that Android 11 will ignore this flag, so it is only a temporary fix.

**So, my question is: what is the right, official, robust way to ensure access to the Download folder for a Flutter app, in the upcoming Android version?**

Usage of the Download folder is a strict requirement.

Thank you!

Comment: From android 11 for download or save any document or make folder in storage, you must save it in one of standard directory like Download, Pictures, Music. Even you cannot create any folder direct in localstorage like /storage/emulated/0/testfolder. We must create  folder like this "/storage/emulated/0/Download/testfolder/files" if we targeting android 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > However, it seems that Android 11 will ignore this flag,

Indeed. It is useless on an Android 11 device. It is only for Android 10 devices.

> > so it is only a temporary fix.

No because for an Android 10 device it will continue to work.

And for an Android 11 device you dont need it as you can just read the public folders like Download again like before 10.